# Interface C function with structures in Fortran

Tags: c, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I want to link a C-function with the corresponding structure in Fortran

```c
struct ovf_file {
    bool found;
    bool is_ovf;
    int n_segments;
    struct ovf_file_handle *_file_handle;
};
DLLEXPORT struct ovf_file * ovf_open(const char *filename);
```

This is my attempt to do it:

```fortran
module ovf
    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
    implicit none

    type, bind(c) :: ovf_file
      logical(c_bool)   :: found
      logical(c_bool)   :: is_ovf
      integer(c_int)    :: n_segments
      type(c_ptr)       :: file_handle
    end type ovf_file
end module ovf

program main
    use ovf
    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
    implicit none
    type(ovf_file)               :: file_handle

    interface
      function ovf_open(filename) bind ( C, name = "ovf_open" ) result(handle)
        character(len=1, kind=c_char), intent(in) :: filename
        type(ovf_file)                            :: handle
      end function ovf_open
    end interface

    file_handle = ovf_open("testfile.ovf"//C_NULL_CHAR)
end program main
```

Which is what I usually do to interface C, but gfortran (or ifort) won't compile this code (I haven't even tried to link it to the C binary). Here is the compiler output:

```
gfortran -c src/fortran_wrapper.f90                                                                                                                                                               [±master ●●]
src/fortran_wrapper.f90:22:30:

         character(len=1, kind=c_char), intent(in) :: filename
                              1
Error: Parameter ‘c_char’ at (1) has not been declared or is a variable, which does not reduce to a constant expression
src/fortran_wrapper.f90:23:22:

         type(ovf_file)                            :: handle
                      1
Error: Derived type ‘ovf_file’ at (1) is being used before it is defined
src/fortran_wrapper.f90:30:12:

     ulala = ovf_open("testfile.ovf"//C_NULL_CHAR)
            1
Error: Type mismatch in argument ‘filename’ at (1); passed CHARACTER(1) to REAL(4)
src/fortran_wrapper.f90:30:12:

     ulala = ovf_open("testfile.ovf"//C_NULL_CHAR)
            1
Error: Can't convert REAL(4) to TYPE(ovf_file) at (1)
```

How come that it knows C-types in the module, but not the program, even though I have the same use-clause? Why can't it find the type even though I include the module?

I can only find very simple use cases for C-interoperability. None which explain structures or C-strings. How do I do this properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to repeat "use iso_c_binding" in the interface (just after function ovf …)

Or you can import C symbols. This is a pity but interfaces do not know used modules.

Comment: You are right. I also had to add ```use ovf``` in the interface and then it worked. Thanks